# Ample plus generating of sections implies very ample?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be smooth projective, we know if a line bundle is very ample, then $H^0(X,L)^{\otimes n}\to H^0(X,L^{\otimes n})$ is surjective.

My question is: If we know $L$ is an ample line bundle, and in addition that $H^0(X,L)^{\otimes n}\to H^0(X,L^{\otimes n})$ is surjective for all $n\geq 1$, is $L$ very ample?

(In the case things go wrong when $X$ is a curve, is the above true if $dim X\geq 2$?)

Thanks!

Comment: Your first statement is wrong. Even for a very ample bundle, the first map is not necessarily onto. The second statement is correct.

Comment: @Mohan Could you explain a little more on the first and provide a reference for the second? Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you look up Hartshorne. For example, he proves (Theorem of Halphen) that a general degree $g+3$ divisor on a genus $g$ curve is very ample. Then, using Riemann-Roch you can show that the map you describe is not onto for $n=2$, since $\dim H^0(L^2)>\dim H^0(L)^{\otimes 2}$ for $g>>0$. The second part is easier.